# Is having an entirely open-source website a stupid idea?

Tags: website

I may or may not be participating in an argument and I hold the idea that a 100% open-source website is not a great idea. Suppose you are running a website with millions of users signed up. Is it feasible in any way to have every piece of code responsible for that website being open to the public?

Comment: I feel you're going to need to define "every piece of code" and in particular where you think the boundary lies - is information stored in a database "code"? Exposing user's personal details is clearly both feasible and a stupid idea; multiple companies have done it after all, if not intentionally.

Comment: There are also a lot of questions about things like firmware blobs, processor microcode and about the infrastructure for getting the information to users (core Internet routers etc). How much of that is included in "every piece of code responsible for that website being open to the public"?

Comment: This question might get closed for being ambiguous -- I think there is a good question in here, but right now you ask both if it is "feasible" for such source disclosure to be possible but then also ask if it is a "not a great idea" to make such a disclosure (a subjective question, already predicted on the feasibility of doing so at all). Do you mean it is not possible to make money off such a website, or that the published state of the site's code cannot hope to keep up with ongoing changes in the deployed running site, or that the site will be vulnerable to security bugs, or something else?

Comment: If you're not participating in the argument, why are you advancing your ideas? :) Having a completely open-source based LAMP server doesn't imply that you're publishing the backend PHP code, MySQL passwords, schemas, etc. Programming languages and infrastructure can be open-source without requiring the programs to be released.

Answer (score 5):

It is feasible to have the website source code (frontend, backend, administration tools) Open Source. High-profile examples of Open Source backend code include MediaWiki sites (e.g. Wikipedia), and Wordpress sites (the world's most popular CMS). In the past, the Reddit source code was also Open Source.

But you don't see many large-scale *companies* open sourcing all of their code. This is for business reasons, not for reasons of technology, security, or licensing. Many businesses benefit from offering a platform, especially in the social media space. Since platforms depend on network effects, it's somewhat of a “winner takes all” market and businesses will generally try to stifle competition. This is generally incompatible with Open Source, which invites collaboration and involves sharing value with competitors. More generally, Open Sourcing their websites or backends simply has no benefit to many businesses. And that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

With a little digging, I find that GNU [Savannah](https://savannah.gnu.org/) is running entirely on free software, top-to-bottom, and currently has over 25,000 registered users.

GitLab used to be entirely free, passing the [GNU ethical evaluation](https://www.fsf.org/news/gnu-releases-ethical-evaluations-of-code-hosting-services) in 2016, at which time [GitLab say](https://about.gitlab.com/company/history/) they had "*millions of users*".

As Amon points out, corporate projects tend not to open up their infrastructure, and community projects that scale up past that tend to federate rather than having a single monolithic million-user site.  By way of example, how many users does [Matrix](https://matrix.org/) have, nearly all of whom are running on an entirely free software stack?  Nobody knows, because there's no central Matrix server.  But when the matrix.org homeserver (which is just a single homeserver, albeit a very large one) was [penetrated in 2019](https://www.reddit.com/r/pwned/comments/bca7ge/matrixorg_chat_server_homepage_defaced_55m/), they said about 5.5 million accounts had their hashes exfiltrated, so I strongly suspect the Matrix user base is well into seven figures, more likely eight.

So some have done it, and thereby provided useful and usable services, which for me at least proves it's not a stupid idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several factors at play here, and I can shine a light on the feasibility of these.

### Security

Let me give you a code example.

```
function handleLogin(username: String, password_guess: String) {
   listOfPasswords = CoolFileManagerLibrary.open("secrets.json")
   cookies.add(listOfPasswords)
   ...
}
```

This code is open source, but you don't have to make secrets.json open source (it is data not code), so it is feasible from this angle of the security persepctive.

However, let's say Hacker A finds a security vulnerability in CoolFileManagerLibrary, and posts it on a hacking site. Hacker B read your websites code, so they know that it uses CoolFileManager library, and exactly where your website uses it, so therefore can then exploit this.

So this is bad from that perspective.

Another negative security angle goes like this: Hacker C can read your code, and discovers a MASSIVE vulnerability. Your website adds the list of passwords to cookies. If they hadn't had access to your source code, it is highly unlikely that he would know this if he didn't have access to your code.

HOWEVER, there is a massive benefit of Open Source code in the security domain. White Hat Hacker D audits your code, and finds this issue (which he wouldn't have been able to find without source code). He reports it privately to you, and you fix it up. White Hat Hacker D doesn't even need to be a security researcher, they could just be an active member who contributes to your code, or a random person just browsing your code.

Generally, from personal experience, you are more likely to encounter people like White Hat Hacker D, and less like Hackers A, B and C.

### Competitiveness

Let's say you come up with a really cool website idea, maybe a forum website that is better than all other websites from some reason.
That's great, but if your code is open source, websites like, ahem, Stack Exchange can just copy all your code, and give you some tiny, hard-to-find credit. Suddenly your website isn't competitive anymore.

There is a solution to this however. Just use a copyleft license like the GPL. If anyone copies your code, they also have to make their code open source, which would make their website open to this issue. I forget where I got this from, but I remember reading a quote like this:

`Copyleft licenses like the GPL make your code like a can of toxic waste. Your competitors can touch it, but they probably don't want to.`

It couldn't be more true.

Thank you for reading, and I hope I have shone a light on the pluses and minuses of open source websites.

Answer (score 0):

It is feasible, but unless you want to make a point about your commitment to the open source philosophy, there is little reason to.

- Your website is in most cases highly specific to your organization and its specific needs. So the code has little use to anyone else.
- All your HTML and JavaScript that is executed in the web browser is source-available anyway due to the way the web works. (As long as you don't minify your JavaScript)
- Users have no way to confirm that the backend code you have on your public sourcecode repository is also the code that *actually* runs on your backend. So if you want to convince the end-users that your website backend doesn't do any shady stuff, you won't convince them by publishing your sourcecode.
- There are very few open source licenses which require that you publish the code of a website backend which incorporates licensed code. The only license I can think of is the AGPL, and that one only requires to publish your sourcecode if you modify the AGPL code incorporated into your website backend.

If you want to build a security argument: See [Linus's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus%27s_law).

Comment: While the JavaScript is nominally source-available, nobody sane tries to work on the minimised form typically sent to the browser. Committing to make a readable, modifiable version available is a major step towards allowing it to be reused.